# Verilog negation operator on inout-type signals

Tags: verilog, simulation

```
inout b,c;
assign c = ~b;
```

In the code above, doing such *assign* will result in **XXX** unknown situation which I presume is due to conflicting drivers?

However, *assign c = b;* does not result in **XXX** unknown situation though. Why?

I tried to use *not a1(c, b);* , but I think the simple *not* primitive gate does not support *inout* type

Any suggestions or comments ?

```
vcs.log:44:Error-[IGOE] Illegal gate output expression
vcs.log-45-TB.v, 49
vcs.log-46-  The following expression is illegally connected to gate.
vcs.log-47-  Expression: c
vcs.log-48-  Source info: not a1(c, b);
vcs.log-49- The gate connection must be a scalar net or bit-select of vector net.
```

Comment: What are you trying to design? Is `c` always an output, and `b` always an input (if so, why notmake the ports: `input b, output c`)? Have you connected `b` and `c` to anything else?

Comment: @TomCarpenter Please stick with `inout b, c;`  ,  `b` and `c` are connected to their output generation logic of course, which is how `inout` works internally.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I am actually simulating coding for two devices, hence two **inout** ports as you saw above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generation of `X`s has nothing to do with `inout` ports—it has to do with which expressions can propagate the `Z` state. Boolean and arithmetic expressions as well as gate-level primitives treat the `Z` state the same as `X`. So the boolean negation of `Z` is always `X`.

A direct assignment and the conditional operator can propagate `Z` states. MOS primitives can too.

So the following would work in Verilog:

```
assign c = (b===3'bz) ? 3'bz : ~b; // need to know the size of b
```

In SystemVerilog:

```
assign c = (b==='z) ? 'z : ~b;
```

Comment: thanks for the info.  By the way, the issue is solved by modifying the internal input and output paths of the `inout` port